# Using postfix for sneakemail style setup

Tags: postfix, filter

I'm trying to setup postfix on my own server to be my own personal sneakemail service. For those of you unfamiliar, sneakemail allows you to generate email addresses that are more or less disposable, so when you sign up for a service, you provide your sneakemail address and it gets forwarded to your normal account. If you do give unique addresses for all the services you use then you'll be able to identify the sources of spam and if you so desire, cut off that address.

I've looked at some of the filtering options for postfix but I'm not sure which option I should use. I already have postfix set up to allow emails only for my @domain but I would like to be able to set up a filter to decide who these emails should be delivered to, and optionally be able to just ignore the email, or bounce it back as undeliverable, or pass it on to the correct recipient.

What specific  documentation can guide me to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you intend to set up the disposable email addresses.

Broadly speaking, there are 2 methods:

- use a specific prefix or postfix for known users and use recipient_delimiter to parse these
- use a web-tool to generate random addresses on-the-fly and link them for a period of time to a provided external address

The former is much easier to implement, as all configruation is done inside the postfix system (with the exception of creating real users), and provides longer-term faux addresses - including unlimited aliases for each real user.

The latter provides much more control, and does not require real email users to be created.

You would then have the web tool edit or fill up an external lookup table (in MySQL or LDAP or the like) that links a *hd7924gh79rfg723479@example.com* address to their external address.
You could use a direct postfix lookup with such a setup, without using a custom filter.
**Virtual_alias_maps** allows this behaviour for any address.

Of course, many more solutions are possible, using any combination of external lookups and filters, policy servers, and whatnot.